# Do I keep my guns through later prestiges with their levels still there and not reset?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I've recently prestiged and I've wondered with the prestige token if I activate the unlock gear does that mean I take that thing I chose to keep go through **all** of the future prestige's or do I only keep it for that specific prestige (e.g. prestige 2) as I previously tried and this **did not** work? I've gotten my MK14 up to level **31** with **everything** unlocked and don't want to lose all of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The unlock token will keep your gear (weapon in this case) unlocked for all future prestiges, but ***it will not keep the experience, camo, attachments, etc for that weapon unlocked***.  Those you will have to re-acquire on each prestige.  For more info, read [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/113084/do-i-keep-my-guns-through-later-prestiges-with-their-levels-still-there-and-not).

> Unlock Gear (can be weapons, equipment, perks, deathstreaks, available at 1st Prestige, also they will be carried on through future prestige levels. **Unlocked weapons will be reset to weapon level 1 upon prestiging**. All unlocked attachments and camouflages are lost in this process, except winter camo)

Answer (score 3):

The item will stay with you for all your prestiges (to prestige 10). It will not lock after you prestige and is not limited to just 1 prestige.